# C# - Serial Port Listening - How to print data into textBox

Tags: c#, serial-port

I want to create Serial port listener with GUI.
I'm trying to print received data into `textBox`. When i click button program has to start listening, everything works but not printing into `textBox`.
Here is `EventHandler` code:

```
void serialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            textBox1.AppendText(indata + "\r\n");
        }
```

And the button code which starts listening:

```
mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
mySerialPort.Open();
```

Need some help :)

Comment: You cannot update UI from the DataReceivedEvent, it is fired on a worker thread.  Why you don't get an InvalidOperationException is not obvious, be sure that you did not disable it.

Comment: maybe you need to change mySerialPort.ReadTimeout , btw by default it 500 ms. maybe 500 is not enough

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RichTextBox` as follows:

**1st option**:

```
RichTextBox1.Text += sp.ReadExisting() + "\n";
```

**2nd option** - The second option uses delegate, you can say, a signature of method:

```
public delegate void AddDataDelegate(String myString);
public AddDataDelegate myDelegate;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.myDelegate = new AddDataDelegate(AddDataMethod);
}

public void AddDataMethod(String myString)
{
    TextBox1.AppendText(myString);
}

private void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
   string s= sp.ReadExisting();

   TextBox1.Invoke(this.myDelegate, new Object[] {s});       
}
```